Curious if there is an idiom for “so as not to deceive”
Basically the title. I wonder if the phrase “so as not to deceive” has any variations, perhaps with a figurative meaning. In Ukrainian there is “Don’t want to bring woe” to wish that positive evaluation would not bring bad luck. In Ukrainian this saying is somehow superstitious and we add it in post-sentence position. I tried to outline this question as well as I could; I appreciate your insight, community.

I'm not sure how “so as not to deceive” differs from "honestly, candidly, openly", so perhaps put one's cards on the table might be what you're looking for. Otherwise, there's the stock phrase for the avoidance of doubt.

The title and the expanded question don't seem to match. The title is about being transparent, but the Ukrainian saying seems to be more about positive affirmation or blessing. I wonder if we should be focussing more on closing sayings such as "Hopefully that helps."

This is not clear: In Ukrainian there is “Don’t want to bring woe” to wish that positive evaluation would not bring bad luck.   What do you mean by "positive evaluation"?  Praising something? Like a jinx? You say  "The car has been very reliable" and now you're afraid it will break down and have to be towed to the mechanic? If so, how is that analogous with "so as not to deceive"? Give an example situation.

@FumbleFingers, I’m not disputing that for the avoidance of doubt may be a stock phrase, but I don’t recognize it. Perhaps it’s a British expression?

@PaulTanenbaum: That's an unexpected but quite distinct US/UK usage split! I included a link to the NGram chart for the "all" English corpus before, but as this one shows, if I chart the eng_us_2019 and eng_gb_2019 corpuses separately, the tiny number of AmE instances could probably be fully accounted for by misclassifications! I'd have thought there would be a similar expression in AmE, though.

Are you thinking of something like "full disclosure"?   blah blah blah blah.  Full disclosure, we're owned by Monopolies-R-Us Corporation.

@TimR Yes, I exactly mean ‘praising something’. “Jinx” is the right word for this. I was doubtful about “as not to decieve” as it was a Google translate result, and at the time couldn’t find anything remotely similar to what I was looking for. The example about the car is spot on.

@TimR So in Ukrainian we say “This car has been very reliable; not to jinx it.” we add the Ukrainian equivalent of “jinx” right at the end. Could you tell me if a native speaker ever says it like? Do you use a “jinx” at the end of the sentence so as to protect yourself from bad luck by saying this word out loud; I’m curious to what extent native speakers are superstitious with their statements. Thank you for your help.

Some speakers are superstitious, others not.  After saying the car has been reliable, we might say "knock on wood!" to ward off bad luck, and if we're sitting at a wooden table, we might actually knock on the table with our knuckles too. Or we might say "I'm not going to say the car has been reliable. I don't want to jinx it."   A lot of sports fans are superstitious, as are many athletes.

My sons played soccer in the US and they have their favorite football teams in other parts of the world, England, Spain, Argentina, wherever. If they're watching a game on TV, and their favorite team is ahead, they want to pull their hair out if my wife comes into the room and innocently says "Yay! Your team is winning."

They call it "commentator's curse" when this happens in televised snooker matches in the UK (commentator points out how good the current player is at the current type of shot, which then goes horribly wrong).

"avoidance of doubt" is not a "stock phrase" but it is good in any English. I don't understand how a native speaker could object to that phrase. I really don't. But it doesn't answer the question.

The title of this question should probably be modified from "so as not to deceive" to "so as not to jinx it".
We have an expression with that meaning: "knock on wood"
Ukrainian: "This car has been very reliable; not to jinx it."
English: "This car has been very reliable; knock on wood."
Then, you literally find a wooden object around you, and tap that with your knuckles.   Otherwise the bad luck could still be a threat.

Thank you for summing it up!
